# Geodesics of sphere mapped to square question

Tags: transformation, spheres, conformal-geometry, geodesic

I'm trying to accurately draw the mappings depicted.

Finitely many geodesics (the curved lines) of the 2-sphere are being mapped to the unit square. I'm not sure if that is captured in the notation but I was not sure how to incorporate the geodesics into the notation. The poles of the sphere are mapped to (0,0) and (1,1) (as pictured below), and for the rotated one, (1,0) and (0,1). The intersections of the two graphs can be seen in the uppermost graph.

Are the drawings accurate representations of the mappings or could they be improved?

$ S^2 \mapsto [0,1]\times[0,1] $

[image]

Comment: Your picture depicts one set of mappings, but without knowing more about the intended mappings I can't say that it's the intended mapping. For example, do you know for sure that the geodesics are not being mapped to zig zag patterns on the square?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the specific equation of the mapping. If I have the equations for the geodesics on the squares is that enough to specify the exact mapping?

Comment: That sounds as if that would be enough.